# Lock and Condition about thread communication in java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, java-threads

I'm a java beginner and I write below code while learning `Thread` in java. I think, if I lock in `Resource.set()` and comment out the `Lock.unlock()`, the code in `Resource.out()` can't be executed because I can't unlock in when I want to execute out method. BTW, whether I comment out the unlock in the `set()` or in `out()`, the program will execute in this way:

> Thread[Thread-1,5,main]....Produce....chicken1
>   Thread[Thread-2,5,main]....Consume..........chicken1
>   Thread[Thread-0,5,main]....Produce....chicken2
>   Thread[Thread-3,5,main]....Consume..........chicken2   ......

I think a long time and don't understand about it. I just learned it, maybe I have a wrong understanding,so I hope someone's help. 
  Please forgive my poor English. Thank you very much. My code is here:

```
package Thread;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ThreadStudying {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Resource r = new Resource();
    Thread t0 = new Thread(new Producer(r));
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Producer(r));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Consumer(r));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new Consumer(r));

    t0.start();
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
}

static class Resource {
    private String name;
    private int count = 1;
    boolean isOut = false;

    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition pro_con = lock.newCondition();
    Condition consu_con = lock.newCondition();

    public void set(String name) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (isOut) {
                try {
                    pro_con.await();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            this.name = name + count;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "....Produce...." + this.name);
            count++;

            isOut = true;
            consu_con.signal();
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void out() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (!isOut) {
                try {
                    consu_con.await();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "....Consume.........." + this.name);

            isOut = false;
            pro_con.signal();
        }
        finally {
            //lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

static class Producer implements Runnable {
    Resource r;

    Producer(Resource r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            r.set("chicken");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

static class Consumer implements Runnable {
    Resource r;

    Consumer(Resource r) {
        this.r = r;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            r.out();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both producer and consumer, you are calling `lock.await` repeatly by

```
while (true) {
    //
}
```

From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await()), when you call `lock.await` :

> The lock associated with this Condition is atomically released

So, whether you comment out `lock.unlock` or not, both producer and consumer will not be blocked.

**P.S.** Use below code to log more details about getting and releasing lock:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ThreadStudying {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Resource r = new Resource();
    Thread t0 = new Thread(new Producer(r), "Producer 1");
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Producer(r), "Producer 2");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Consumer(r), "Consumer 1");
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new Consumer(r), "Consumer 2");

    t0.start();
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
}

static class Resource {
    private String name;
    private int count = 1;
    boolean isOut = false;

    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition pro_con = lock.newCondition();
    Condition consu_con = lock.newCondition();

    public void set(String name) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "before lock");
        lock.lock();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "get lock");
        try {
            while (isOut) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "release lock");
                    pro_con.await();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            this.name = name + count;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "....Produce...." + this.name);
            count++;

            isOut = true;
            consu_con.signal();
        }
        finally {

        }
    }

    public void out() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "before lock");
        lock.lock();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "get lock");
        try {
            while (!isOut) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "release lock");
                    consu_con.await();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "....Consume.........." + this.name);

            isOut = false;
            pro_con.signal();
        }
        finally {
            //lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

static class Producer implements Runnable {
    Resource r;

    Producer(Resource r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            r.set("chicken");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

static class Consumer implements Runnable {
    Resource r;

    Consumer(Resource r) {
        this.r = r;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            r.out();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FirstOfAll, "if I lock in Resource.set() and comment out the Lock.unlock(), the code in Resource.out() can't be executed ". This statement of yours is wrong.

Let me clarify why,

In your posted code, where `out()` has no unlock. I assume you have no problem that one of the `Consumer` threads (`t2` or `t3`) have no problem in acquiring the lock.

So lets say `t2` acquired the lock, while entering `out()` method and didn't release the lock while exiting `out()` method. But you overlooked the fact that `out()` method is executed in infinite loop inside `run()` method of `Consumer` Runnable. So when `t2` exits `out()`, sleep of `500` milliseconds; its still in possession of the lock. When it enters the `out()` method in its next iteration, it executes `Lock.lock()` on the same lock it already has. Since the lock is `Reentrant` Lock, it proceeds and executes `await()` where it releases the lock; and the other threads(`Producer` threads) waiting on the lock gets chance to acquire the lock.